# Electric Dipole inside a cavity of conducting sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, electrostatics, potential, dipole

In the problem, a cavity is taken out of a uniform conducting sphere. Inside the cavity, a dipole is placed as shown in the fig. find the potential at point P[image]

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential must be constant inside of a non-driven conductor.  This means that the resultant E field in the conductor (from the dipole and the shifted electrons in the sphere) must be zero. Place a Gaussian surface just outside (or inside) of the sphere.